# passing variable from MKAnnotationView to segue

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have an MKMapView, that I drop a number of pins on from an array. Each map pin has an MKAnnotationView that links to a segue and another controller.

All of this is working perfectly now, but I can't see how to pass a variable through the MKAnnotationView to the segue.

I can work with either passing a string or an integer, as I could pass a username as a string, or pass the id of the array and use that in the second view controller after the segue.

My working code for looping through my array, dropping the pins, adding the annotations, and then calling the segue is as below.

This all works fine, populates the map, drops the bins, and the annotations work and link to the new segue. This is all perfect!

I just need to be able to pass a variable through from the map pin array to the second view controller segue.

```
- (void)loadMapPins {
  for (int i=0; i<maparray.count; i++){
    Location *item = _feedItems1[i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = {[item.latitude doubleValue], [item.longitude doubleValue]};
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = myCoordinate;
    point.title = item.firstname;
    point.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", item.username];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
  }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {
  if (annotation == self.mapView.userLocation) return nil;
  static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
  MKPinAnnotationView* customPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
  customPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  customPin.animatesDrop = YES;
  customPin.canShowCallout = YES;
  UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  customPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
  return customPin;
}

- (IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showProfileFromMap" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this `MKMapViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    CustomAnnotationClass *annotation = view.annotation;
    selectedAnnotationVariable = annotation.yourProperty;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"performSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This looks really good, and using this, I have managed to pass the title or subtitle of the annotation view. Is there any way this can send a field that is not visible on the map pin callout? It seems that title and subtitle are the only two items I can pass? I would love to be able to pass an ID reference that is not shown on the map pin.

Comment: I edited my answer. You want to get the Annotation from the View and than get any properties you need directly from the Annotation. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to add your edited code, but I get the error "Unknown type name ‘MKAnnotation’; did you mean ‘MKAnnotationView’?". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Finally have this working now!! Thanks for your patience and help!